# OpenCV: Finding the color intensity

Tags: python, opencv, colors, image-recognition

I want to write a program to see whether the red **color intensity** is the **dominant color**. If the brown color intensity is **greater than the threshold**. Then the program will print out "Detected".

[image]

For example, the red color in the photo is the dominant color, so the program should print out "Detected"!.

I have written somethings like this:

```
lower_red = np.array([110, 50, 50], dtype=np.uint8)
upper_red = np.array([130,255,255], dtype=np.uint8)
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_red, upper_red)
res = cv2.bitwise_and(frame,frame, mask= mask)
```

However, it only converts the color of the image, but the giving the intensity. How can I get the Boolean value that the image has more red color or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should convert your image to the HSV color space. It is simple to separate red color in that space: red color will have Hue near [0-10] and [160-180].
Then you can check whether ratio of red color is greater than threshold.

```
(pseudocode)

fun isRedColorGreaterThanThreshold(image, threshold)
  imageHSV = convertToHSV(image)
  channels = split(imageHSV)
  Hue = channels[0]
  ratio = countNonZero((0 < Hue < 10) or (160 < Hue < 180)) / image.total()

  return ratio > threshold
```

Comment: what is the meaning of "channels = split(imageHSV)"?

Comment: "channels" is a vector of bands, Hue = channels[0], Saturation = channels[1], Value = channels[2], opencv has function [split](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#split) that works this way

Comment: One more question: what is the meaning of "image.total()"? Is it the total number of pixel in the image?

Comment: Yes, it is. Pls, refer to [opencv docs](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-total)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I still have some problems 1) What if I am not detecting the additive color, but some others color like brown. Then do i need to consider both H,S and  V?     2) And I found out that there is a lot of noise. For the flower pic above, the ratio is just 0.38. Do I need to do some preprocess to eliminate the background?